# Definition of Elementary Matrices

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination, kronecker-delta

I'm a bit confused about the definition of [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) which are used to represent elementary row operations on an extended coefficient matrix when doing the [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

In my lecture at uni, the elementary matrix was defined with the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) like so:

$$E_{ij} = (\delta_{ii'} \delta_{jj'})_{1 \leq i', j' \leq m}$$

And a given example was

$$ E_{12} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Reading some supplementary literature cleared up how elementary matrices are constructed, as the book defined $E_{ij}$ to be a [single-entry matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-entry_matrix) and that *elementary matrices* are constructed by adding a single-entry matrix (or a multiple thereof) to the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

For example the elementary matrix representing the row transformation of adding the jth row to he ith row of a matrix $A$ was defined as
$$ Q_{ij} = I_m + E_{ij}$$ where it then could be applied to $A$ like so: $$A' = Q_{ij} \cdot A$$ where $A'$ would be the transformed matrix.

This definition makes intuitively way more sense to me than the definition of my university, where we would skip the definition of single-entry matrices and $Q_{ij}$ to just define the same transformation as $A' = (I_m + E_{ij}) \cdot A$.

1. Am I correct to assume that the definition of elementary matrices of my Uni is just wrong?
2. Even if my prof meant to say that $E_{ij}$ is a single-entry matrix; how would one calculate $E_{ij}$ using the two kronecker deltas? I know that the identity matrix can be defined through the kronecker delta like so: $I_m = (\delta_{ij})$ but I have a hard time picturing how a single-entry matrix is calculated through the two kronecker deltas.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do they make it so complicated ? An elementary matrix results from preforming an elementary operation on the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer your question 2 first. The expression with the kronecker deltas is
$$
E_{ij} = (\delta_{ii'}\delta_{jj'})_{1\leq i',j' \leq m}
$$
This means that the entry at row $i'$, column $j'$ of the matrix $E_{ij}$ is given by 
$$\delta_{ii'}\delta_{jj'}$$ 
What value is this expression? Since for any $x,y$ we have $\delta_{xy}=1$ if $x=y$ and $\delta_{xy}=0$ otherwise, we see that $\delta_{ii'}\delta_{jj'}=1$ if and only if both $i=i'$ and $j=j'$ hold, and otherwise the product is zero.

This means that exactly one entry of $E_{ij}$ is nonzero, namely the one at row $i$ and column $j$, as desired. (But I can agree that the notation with the deltas is a bit complicated)

Your question 1 is a bit harder for me to answer, let's see if I understand you correctly:

If the definition given in lecture was that $E_{ij}$ is an elementary matrix, I'd say the definition is wrong. Just as the Wikipedia link you give says, an elementary matrix is a matrix that is one elementary row operation away from the identity matrix. You can express these matrices as $I+kE_{ij}$ for some choice of indices $i,j$ and scalar $k$, or as an identity matrix where you swap two rows (see the examples on the wiki page).

I would guess that since your book explains elementary matrices in this way, maybe you could double-check what was said during the lecture, to be sure you didn't misunderstand? It would be odd if the book and lecturer said different things, so to say.

Comment: In the script of my lecture it says "Definition: A matrix with exactly one entry 1 and all other entries 0 is called elementary matrix." So it is definitely wrong. Your explanation of the kronecker deltas helped me a lot! Thank you very much.